# Django - implementing models.FileField using MEDIA_ROOT throws permission errors

Tags: django

I am trying to implement a models.FileField (as a side note models.ImageField complains that I do not have Pillow, but I will try to install it once this is solved). When I use MEDIA_ROOT and try to upload a file from Admin I get this error:

> PermissionError at /admin/resume/project/9/change/
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/resume'
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/resume/project/9/change/ Django Version:
>     2.0.3 Exception Type:   PermissionError Exception Value:
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/resume'
>
> Exception Location:
>     /home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/djangoresume/lib/python3.4/os.py in
>   makedirs, line 237 Python Executable:
>     /home/kinkyboy/virtualenv/djangoresume/bin/python3 Python Version:
>     3.4.3 ..

This is the relevant part of the code.

```
### project/settings.py
RUNNING_DEVSERVER = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')
DEBUG = RUNNING_DEVSERVER
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = '/resume/'
MEDIA_URL = '/resume/'

### project/urls.py
..
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
  urlpatterns = [
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
..

### app/models.py
class Project(models.Model):
  ..
  image = models.FileField(upload_to='img/',blank=True)

### app/index.html
<p>Use this below: {{proj.image.url}}</p>
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url('{% static '<use the image url>' %}');">
```

Structure of my project:

```
Project
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── resume
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── fixtures
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── static
    │   └── resume
    │       ├── img
    │       ├── ...
    ├── templates
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

EDIT: this solves my problem

```
### project/settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "resume/")
MEDIA_URL = '/'  #this sets the relative path from /app for uploaded files

### app/models.py
image = models.FileField(upload_to='static/resume/img/',blank=True)

### app/index.html
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url('{{ proj.image.url }}');">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation on image and file fields in the FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields) you need to:

1. Specify the full path to the directory in your MEDIA_ROOT
2. Make sure that the user running your web server does have write access to the directory specified by your MEDIA_ROOT directory

Comment: That solves the upload. Now I am tyring to figure out how to show the image in the template